# React-Native type is invalid -- expected a string

Tags: react-native, mobile

I'm starting with react native and I find the next mistake, I'm a little disoriented.

From App.js I import the component Home.js, but I get the following error:

**### ERROR #################**

*Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) 
but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.*

**#### App.js #############**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import { Home } from './componentes/Home';

export default class App extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Home />
      </View>
  );
}
```

**### ./componentes/Home.js ###########**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component{
    render() {
      return (
        <Text>Home</Text>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is the English StackOverflow, please only ask questions in English here.

Comment: his question is valid, jus he has posted in whatever labguage, maybe spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in your `App.js` change your way of importing Home to ,

```
import  Home  from './componentes/Home';
```

AND NOT THE ONE BELOW

```
import { Home } from './componentes/Home';
```

hope it helps , feel free for doubts